# What is the development workflow with IBM Bluemix and CloudFoundry?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm starting out with IBM Bluemix and CloudFoundry.  Using the tutorial examples of the Node.js/Cloudant app I have a dev workflow that seems really slow.  What is the best practice for development with cf?

Here's what I do now

1. Edit my files locally
2. `cf push myapp`
3. **Wait for a long time for the app to deploy**
4. Test and find an error
5. Repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a Node.js application, you can use `Bluemix Live Sync` to quickly update the application instance on Bluemix and develop as you would on the desktop without redeploying.

You can choose to download the `bl` cli to sync with a local directory using `Desktop Sync`, or set up your project on `DevOps Services` and edit the code directly in your browser using Live Edit. Look in the documentation for `Bluemix Live Sync`.

https://developer.ibm.com/devops-services/2015/02/13/everything-kitchen-sync-bluemix-live-sync/

If you are doing more intensive development, it would be faster for you to set up node locally and push to Bluemix periodically. You can still consume most Bluemix services locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to rely on an architecture resident in Bluemix and you do not have the possibility to test on local you cannot avoid the "push" command and the workflow you described. Regarding point 3, you might have incurred in a platform issue announced at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status.